# Intent not Serializable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

So I have an Activity that I want to pass trough an intent, but it keeps crashing with the following exception: **java.io.NotSerializableException: android.content.Intent**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable{

/* some code */

     detailIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieActivity.class);
     detailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     detailIntent.putExtra("MainActivityReference",this);
     startActivity(detailIntent);


}
```

If you guys could point out my mistake I would be gratefull! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's normal. You have to extract informations you want, serialize them, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have an Activity that I want to pass trough an intent

That is not possible, sorry.

Even if you could make `Activity` implement `Serializable` properly (which is not possible), passing values by `Intent` extras makes *copies*. It is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. Your `MovieActivity` would have a useless `MainActivityReference` extra, pointing to some incomplete, detatched copy of your `MainActivity`.

Comment: What should i pass then that would allow me to call methods from this activity ?

Comment: @PeterGregz: You don't pass anything. You find some other solution for whatever business problem it is that you are trying to solve. Activities are loosely coupled; one activity does not call methods on another activity.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I will try something different.